# Calculate stream-trace from two tables velocity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, software

There is a programme, which calculates two components of velocity on grid 100x50.

```
x=1,100;
y=1,50;
```

In the end (when programme completes its work) I have two tables of two components of velocity (first table stands for x-comp., second - for y-comp.).
So 100x50 values for each component.

Question: how manually in my program on C++ can I calculate streamtrace of the whole field of velocity? So I want to get [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines) from my values spread in two tables.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to present a clear and focussed question on physics. I don't think that anyone here has a clear idea of what you're talking about in your question.

Comment: The recent edit doesn't make it much better.  This seems to be more of a programming question than a physics one; but it isn't well formulated as either.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but coders don't have any ideas about what streamtrace  is. Code is not pivotal point here, I just want to understand how to get vector  field from table values

Comment: Still not sure what you're trying to ask. You now write "x=1,100; y=1,50;". Do you realize how difficult it is to decipher what you're trying to say? What are x and y supposed to be? The x- and y- components of a velocity at some point? If so, then why are there four numbers listed rather than just two for the x- and y- components of velocity? Try to make more of an effort to express yourself more clearly and before posting read and re-read and edit your question to make sure that it is clear and easy to understand.

Comment: Well, take it easy. I am sorry, if I am not expressing myself very precise. But do you know, what does 'grid' mean, what is computational physics? 
x=1,100, y=1,50 and 100x50 mean that I have 5000 nodes and in every node there are two components of velocity (Vx and Vy). I thought it is obvious, but maybe this source is more about 'pure' physics and not computational but since it is my first question here I did not know and I am sorry for that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily about programming in a specific language rather physics.

Comment: I don't see why this is so hard to understand. If you click the link, its relatively simple to understand. The most confusing part is if what he means by the ',' in the numbers. Perhaps its now clear with edits done that I missed

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/26939/16935)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move in a velocity field, you can do the following.

We will move a point $ \vec{x}(n) $ discretely based on the velocity field $ \vec{v}(\vec{x}, n) $ where $ n $ is the discrete time value
\begin{align}
\vec{x}(n+1) = \vec{x}(n) + \vec{v}(\vec{x}, n)
\end{align}

Its really that simple. Now, if you program it, you just need to make sure you index into $ \vec{v} $ properly.

```
x[n+1] = x[n] + Vx[roundf(x/dx)];
y[n+1] = y[n] + Vy[roundf(y/dy)];
```

where `dx` and `dy` are your grid spacing.

Depending on your needs, you may want to take really small steps or normalize your steps on the grid to the smallest step feasible.

```
int x[N], y[N];
int div = gcd(roundf(Vy[roundf(x/dx)]), roundf(Vy[int(y/dy)]));
x[n+1] = x[n] + roundf(Vx[roundf(x/dx)])/div;
y[n+1] = y[n] + roundf(Vy[roundf(y/dy)])/div;
```

Comment: Thank you!
What is int here? and then how to plot it?

Comment: This is using the Euler method of integration which can be really unstable. Better to use a higher order technique such as Runge-Kutta. You can find a wealth of information in [this paper](https://graphics.ethz.ch/teaching/former/scivis_07/Notes/stuff/StuttgartCourse/VIS-Modules-07-Vector_Field_Visualization.pdf) - see in particular section 5.

Comment: @John, int() is pretty standard floor function in many languages. Plotting is beyond the scope of this post. That is a StackOverflow question, not Physics by any means.

Comment: @Floris, I agree that a higher order method should be used. I feel its beyond the scope.

Comment: You might consider using `roundf()` rather than `int()` for rounding. It takes care of the pesky +- 0.5 at the right time...

Comment: I think that the proper approach is to first try to come up with a good, velocity field function v(x,y) which is continuous function of x and y rather than working directly with the v(x,y) values at discrete integer x and y values. One could, for instance use the values of vx(x,y) and vy(x,y) at the known discrete integer (x,y) points and use a spline fit to get vx(x,y) and vy(x,y) functions which are continuous functions of (x,y) for real values of x and y. After that, one can use the procedure described above to generate the stream paths with arbitrarily small steps.

Comment: Since roundf() is a discontinuous function, the procedure described above will in general result in discontinuities in the slopes of the stream lines. That problem is eliminated if a continuous v(x,y) function of real (x,y) is used instead of directly using one which is only defined for integer values of (x,y) and using roundf() to (discontinuously) go from one point to the next.